Is it possible to upgrade Pixel 4a to Android 14?
My dayjob wants me to upgrade for security reasons. The System Update portion of the settings app isn't offering it to me, but web searches seem to indicate that it's an option.
Does anybody know for sure, and if so, how?

Your employer seems to misunderstand the Android update strategy: it is not important to have Android 14 on your device, it is important to have a device that gets the latest security updates. As Google fixes security issues in all supported Android versions it doesn't matter if you are running 13 or 14, you just need a device that receives security updates. In your case the Pixel 4a is out of support and does not receive Android nor security updates but for other devices it may be different.

OK, thanks. I did accept the security updates.

Pixel 4a is only supported till Android 13. See end of life for Pixel Devices or Google website.
You can flash a custom ROM to upgrade to Android 14 but that involves unlocking bootloader (in the process wiping data in your phone)
Unlocked bootloader may not be acceptable to your employer given that they are insisting that the latest Android version running on your device. But if it is, flashing a custom ROM is the solution ( XDA is a good place to search for custom ROM's).Make sure you follow the installation instructions
IMO it's better to go in for a new device that supports Android 14 and maybe 15 or more rather than getting into flashing a custom ROM to upgrade.
BTW, Pixel 4a is my standby device.

Thanks. 4a is my carry device; Pixel 2 is my standby :). I guess it's time to upgrade. I see Pixel 7s for a decent price.
